# Visual Studio 2010: Consume first command name

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to turn on the "[consume-first](http://www.martinwilley.com/blog/2009/12/04/VisualStudio2010IntellisenseConsumeFirst.aspx)" functionality in Visual Studio 2010, but unfortunately my install of Resharper has hijacked the Ctrl+Alt+Space shortcut for its own purposes.

Anyone know what the command name is for consume first so I can rebind it? I'm having no luck searching for it in the (still far too small) keyboard options dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control-Alt-Space is normally mapped to `Edit.ToggleCompletionMode`.